# Client side Asynchronous WCF Vs Server side Asynchronous WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

Which is better off the two in terms of performance and thread complexity: "Server side Asynchronous WCF" or "Client side Asynchronous WCF" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are equally important:

- If you do operations synchronously on the server then you are blocking the server
- If you do synchronous calls on the client then you are blocking the client

So ideally all I/O intensive tasks should be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The only way either of the client-side or server-side asynchronous calls could be told better is how they are implemented. Poor design and workflow would spell disastrous system performance.

The decision for client-side or server-side asynchronous calls should be taken on the basis of who's making the call. A thumb-rule to determine the asynchronous function call is to always avoid server-side programming. The server will be serving to a number of clients and hence needs as much processor and memory space as possible. The client would be running on its own and should not be too dependent on the server. It may well be that the client's request may be processed by the server in a pipeline of processes, so until its process is processed the client should be able to carry on on its own. Thus, client-side asynchronous call to the server is highly recommended.